# Yii: How do I find out which views, controllers, models and styles are being used in a page?

Tags: php, yii

I'm very new to Yii, and I've been asked to take a look at a project, and see if I can add anything.

So to start off, I wanted to find out what files are in play for a certain page, i.e., what Controller, what View, what Model, etc. A friend, who dabbles in Yii told me it can usually be found via the URL itself, like this:

> Sample: localhost/project/index.php?r=site/index
>   Site is the Controller, index is the Action

However, the project I saw returns URLs like so:
`localhost/cdforum/web/index.php/forum/view/id/1`

To which my friend said `"the htaccess must've been modified"`. We assumed the Controller is `forum`, and the Action is `view`

We're not exactly sure if that's accurate. And given a project directory like so:

[image]

I'm not exactly sure what to look for. So I'd like to ask, for the URL above, is there a way to tell which files are responsible for the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can usually get that from url but not necessarily because routing is defined in your config/main.php file in this part of it:

```
array(
    ......
    'components'=>array(
        ......
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                'pattern1'=>'route1',
                'pattern2'=>'route2',
                'pattern3'=>'route3',
             ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Check the rules key of this array is the pattern the url is going to have so your pattern will look like

```
'forum/view/...' => 'the/real/url'
```

then stuff before first backslash is the controller and the second is the action. In that action you will be able to find what models are used.

Hope it helps

Comment: So, if a button has the tag (from inspect form) as follows: `<a href="/cdforum/web/index.php/forum/delete/reply/3/topic/1" id="yt1">Delete</a>`, I can assume that the controller is ForumController, and actionDelete is the action? I've put in an echo statement there that's not firing, though.

Comment: @zack_falcon You can assume that but it might not be correct. The default setting created for you by Yii are like that. First thing after index.php/ is the controller. However you can modify what the url is going to look like in the config/main.php. So look for the pattern that looks like your url as a key of url manager rules array. Value of that key is going to tell you what action is called with that pattern. If I had to guess it is the actionDelete or actionDeleteReply() that accepts two arguments from $_GET reply id and topic id.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to familiarize with this wiki page
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/249/understanding-the-view-rendering-flow/

Then, you can display trace log on your pages:

config/main.php

```
'log'=>array(
    (...)

    'routes'=>array(
        (...)

        array(
          'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
          'levels'=>'trace',
        ),
    ),
),
```